# VZ Address Directory

Tags: ee2, matrix, fieldtype

I'm trying to figure out the best setup for a directory. I'm adding a bunch of stores that have multiple locations so I wanted to set up my entry to have one address field as "headquarters" followed by a matrix of all possible additional addresses.

With this format, Would I still be able to have the directory display all addresses in a list equally? As in if someone was to search for nearby locations, they would see 2-3 headquarters of businesses as well as any relevant secondary addresses?

Comment: How would someone search nearby locations? If the dataset is not to large, you could load it into javascript and do interactive search/sort there. Also if you ever want more detailed or some extra info per location, i would opt for location channel with relation/playa field.

Comment: The data set is going to be pretty huge (essentially every craft store worldwide). I'm trying to make it so I don't have 200 individual listings for Joann's or other large chains. The hope is to have a zip code search or a link drill down similarly to ikea's homepage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you intend to search the directory is certainly a factor as far as your channel structure is concerned. Are you browsing only? And by category or geography? Or are you introducing a geolocated search functionality?

No matter how you handle the browse/search itself, you certainly should be able to assign one location as a "headquarters" simply by having a relationship field and within the non-headquarters location entries, relate them to their parent location/headquarters (if that is appropriate to the organizational structure).

Comment: Ah so they should be kept as individual listings..I was hoping for chain stores that have 200+ I wouldn't have to have that many listings. Most of it will be drill down or keyword search but we were hoping to do a 'shop local' function which would just show you what's near the address you have provided the site.

Comment: The "near" part probably needs geolocation (and distance math, not to difficult) so i would definitely suggest an entry per location and (simple) relationship fields.

Comment: Me too. And for mapping, you can't go wrong with Google Maps for ExpressionEngine from @objectivehtml - amazing functionality for this purpose.

Comment: haha ok that's a lot of entries but it makes sense :) I have google maps functioning however it is just showing a URL to the correct map location and not displaying an actual map.